# AngularJS routing with redirection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on AngularJS with ng-route, have a navigation **Matches**, **Standings** and when I click on **Matches** I want to open a sub navigation **All**, **1st Round**, **Semi Finals** ... and I want by default the **allmatches.html** view to be displayed below.

I wrote something like this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/matches', {
    templateUrl: 'views/matchesmenu.html',
    controller: 'matchesmenuCtrl',
  })
```

to display the matches sub navigation once I click on **Matches** and it works fine. What can I do now to display the **allmatches.html** just below it (I mean by that route to **matches/all**

I tried to add

```
redirectTo : '/matches/all'
```

in

```
 .when('/matches', {
    templateUrl: 'views/matchesmenu.html',
    controller: 'matchesmenuCtrl',
  })
```

but it redirects without displaying the sub navigation.

Example on plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UoTcOlcDQSwveCTbmxyY?p=preview

Comment: Why do you use a route to display a sub navigation?

Comment: The sub nav contains dynamic items received from a factory/controller. I couldn't find a better solution. If I route directly to **matches/all** when I click on **Matches**, what I can do when I click on another item in sub nav? For example, when I click on **Semi Finals** how can I keep the sub nav displayed and replace the below content with the content relative to semi finals?

Comment: You could achieve that by switch on ui-router instead of using `$routeProvier`. In that way you could create state linke like `<a ui-srer="your.state">Submenu item</a>`.

Comment: I never used ui-router can you explain more what I must do? Or provide me with a link to an example?

Comment: Do you need to have your sub-nav section in a separate view? They are just gonna be just list of links rite? Why not have them in the same html as your nav items. Bind the sub-nav list to a scope variable. When user clicks on any of the nav item, assign the sub-nav items to the above scope variable. Hope this answers your question

Comment: I create an answer with an example  for you EddyG.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6016779/pathrik I need the sub-nav to be in a separate view because it uses other controller/factory. Plus it must be displayed only if I click on **Matches** in initial nav. If I click on other item in initial nav such as **Standings** or **Teams** I won't need to display this sub-nav.

Comment: @EddyG "using" different factories, etc. is not a reason for a partial view.

Comment: @EddyG could you create a runnable plnkr of what you have tried right now? In that way I could create a neat solution for you.

Comment: Ok I will post the example on plnkr and send a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, here your are - [runnable plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pmIOcRhLGQo5zJJVwlDX?p=preview). This provides a simple tab handling logic for you.

#### TabView

```
<div ng-controller="TabCtrl">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active' : activeTab === 'all'}">
      <a ng-click="activeTab = 'all'">All</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active' : activeTab === 'first-round'}">
      <a ng-click="activeTab = 'first-round'">1st Round</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active' : activeTab === 'semi-finals'}">
      <a ng-click="activeTab = 'semi-finals'">Semi Finals</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active' : activeTab === 'finals'}">
      <a ng-click="activeTab = 'finals'">Final</a>
    </li>
  </ul> 
  <div>
    <div class="" ng-switch="activeTab">
        <div ng-switch-when="all">
            <div data-ng-include="'first-round.html'"></div>
            <div data-ng-include="'semifinals.html'"></div>
            <div data-ng-include="'finals.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="first-round">
            <div data-ng-include="'first-round.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="semi-finals">
            <div data-ng-include="'semifinals.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="finals">
            <div data-ng-include="'finals.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/matches', {
        templateUrl: 'matchesmenu.html'
      })
      .when('/matches/all', {
        templateUrl: 'allmatches.html'
      })

}).controller('TabCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.activeTab = 'all';
});
```

Comment: Yeah good one. I only wish to know if its possible to update the uri when I click on a sub nav tab. For example, clicking on 1st round tab will make my uri /matches/1stround, and when im on all make it matches/all? If it's complicated the solution you provided is fine for me, thanks.

Comment: @EddyG You can achieve this with ui-router instead of ngRoute. e.g. `$state.go('your.state', {}, {notify: false}) `. Where `notify: false` will not force to rerender your application, it just change the URL based on your state.

Comment: @EddyG is this enough help to get the tick? =)

Comment: Thank you @lin for your efforts. I learned how to use ui.router and it seems better than ngRoute as you said.

Comment: Cheers m8 =) Glad to help ya

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Define your sub menu in controller level

```
$scope.tabs = [
            {title: 'All', url: 'allmatches.html', active: true, type: 'all'},
            {title: '1st Round', url: 'semiFinals.html', active: false, type: 'semi'}
        ];
```

//handle tab click event

```
$scope.tabClick = function (index) {
            angular.forEach($scope.tabs, function (tab) {
                tab.active = false;
            });
            $scope.selectedTab = index;
            $scope.tabs[index].active = true;
        };
```

After that matchesmenu.html load content using ng-include option

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':tab.active}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ><a href="#/log/{{tab.type}}" >{{tab.title}}</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">

            <div class="col-xs-12"  ng-repeat="tab in tabs"  ng-model="tab" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
              <div ng-include src="tab.url" ng-if="tab.active"> </div>
            </div>

</div>
</div>
```